# CakePHP routing with no prefix

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to have no prefix on CakePHP 2.5 routes?

We're trying to achieve a `<domain>/<username>` type route where  would route to a standard Cake url like `<domain>/users/view/XX`. Similar to the Twitter URL structure, although I am not sure a zero-prefix route is possible. If it is, would it also break the standard Cake routing for the other models?

`<domain>/users/view/1` works fine.

I can add a route to routes.php like this, which shortens the URL slightly,

```
Router::connect(
    '/u/*',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view_by_slug')
);
```

However we are wondering if it possible to shorten it even more and achieve a `<domain>/<username>` type prefix.

Edit: For completeness here is the current `view_by_slug()` controller

```
   public function view_by_slug($slug = null) {    
        $user = $this->User->findBySlug($slug);
        debug($user);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
   }
```

Users.slug in the database is a varchar(255)

```
Router::connect(
    '/*', array('controller' => 'users',  'action' => 'view_by_slug')
);
```

Seems to work, however it disables the Cake default routing.

Comment: Nice idea if you don't use links such as domain.com/account, domain.com/messages, domain.com/login etc. If you do, you will need to specify to users upon registration that they cannot use certain usernames, and this could be a very long list. HelloSpeakman's answer should work though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following (untested but it should work)

```
Router::connect('/:slug/', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view_by_slug'), 
    array('slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'pass' => array('slug'))
);

Router::connect('/:slug/controller', array('action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:slug/controller/*');
```